# SSRS Tablix - Each group as group header row

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a dataset looks like
  [image]

Now I want to create a report where Dept as a group should be on row header for each group. looks like
[image]

I tried adding Dept as a parent group, but it appears on a column not as a header on top of each group.

Comment: Just add a total row, set the first column (above Age) to be Dept and then merge the cells across and format accordingly.

Comment: Thanks you Alan :)