# Repeat group header in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

The report output needs to be in the following format:

Group Header - Date1

```
Col1   | Col2   | Col3  
------  ------  -----

aa       11      11.11

bb       22      22.22

cc       33      33.33
```

next page

Group Header - Date2

```
Col1   | Col2   | Col3

dd      44      44.44

ee      55      55.55

ff      66      66.66
```

#### Question

Data will be displayed as part of Tablix with date(group header) as Rowgroup.

I need to display the columns as well as the Group header which is a date variable. The data is grouped by the date in the group header.

How do I display group header in  SSRS?

Thanks

> > > > > > >
> > > > > >             Update: Trying to achieve similar to [SSRS Tablix - Each group as group header row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43123665/ssrs-tablix-each-group-as-group-header-row)
> > > > > >             but with page breaks in between.

While adding a totals row, the row is inserted below the column headers. So I deleted that and inserted a row above the column headers and set the column to row group (In the example, Dept). But the value of the row group is not changing for the next set.(Math to Biology in the example) It seems to be stuck to the first value for all groups. What did I do wrong?

Comment: This is typically something which you would handle in your presentation layer.  What is the ultimate destination for your data?

Comment: The report output is in PDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a tablix(table) with a group on date (gray row) and detail (white rows).

Set the group expression to your date field and set it to page break between each instance of the group.

Be carreful for the group value to be a simple value `Fields!mydate.value` and not something like `First(Fields!mydate.value)`

Add a group line (not new group) below the date header for the column headers (blue row)

[image]

[image]